# Why Array's :+ does not work inside for comprehension?

Tags: arrays, scala, append

```
val tagsArray = tags.split(",")
var trimmedTagsArray: Array[String] = Array()
for(tag <- tagsArray) {
  trimmedTagsArray :+ tag.trim
}
```

*trimmedTagsArray* is empty afterwards, even though *tagsArray* contains elements, and even if I omit the *trim* call.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand the :+ operator. Rather than modifying the existing trimmedTagsArray variable, the :+ is actually returning a new array with the result of the expression "tag.trim" appended to the end. Since you neither yield this result back, or assign it anywhere, this value is discarded.

I believe what you are actually looking for is to replace the line in your for comprehension with the following.

trimmedTagArray = trimmedTagArray :+ tag.trim

While this will accomplish what you want, however, it is not the best solution by far. Instead, try the following...

```
val trimmedTagsArray = for(tag <- tagsArray) yield {
  tag.trim
}
```

The above will create a val (preferred in Scala over var) that has the desired values while avoiding mutable state.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation and your solution. Now I get it. I expected :+ to work like +=. Of course this is nonsense.

Comment: @user1625837 you might find `map` more convenient than a for-expression for simple cases like this. `val trimmedTags = tags.split(",").map(_.trim)`

Comment: Thanks Luigi for your hint, in fact that looks even better.

Comment: @user1625837 This is obvious, but the yield and the map forms are exactly the same, and that is worth knowing. The collections API is also worth knowing. They say it's like 50 common functions?

Answer (score 2):

It works. Just that for(...) {} returns Unit. You want :

```
for(tag <- tagsArray) yield {
  trimmedTagsArray :+ tag.trim
}
```

Comment: I missed something.  I get Array(Array(a), Array(b), Array(c)).  That's OK, just add .flatten.